# Fill the Section background in SwiftUI Form

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have to fill that background of a Section with a certain color like this 
 [image]

By now I tried

```
NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Error message!")
                    }.background(Color.red.opacity(0.2))

                Section {
                    Text("Label 1")
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Label 2")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode.inline)
        }
```

but, there seem to be a predefined padding, so I can't fill the margins

[image]

Comment: The colour you want to change is of section header and section footer.

Comment: @TheTiger No, as you can see in the first picture, I wanna change the color of the section's content (red), not the color of header or footer

Comment: I commented for your `there seem to be a predefined padding, so I can't fill the margins` line. Actually in group tableView there is extra header and footer space ... try setting the height of header or footer to 0.

Comment: @TheTiger The section indeed has a header and footer:  `Section(header:  _, footer: _, content: _)`, but I as know the header and footer are outside of content area, but I only want to sent the content's background to red, is there another header and footer I do not know about? how to set their size ?

Comment: When I looked at Section in Beta 3 IIRC I found that background et al. were applied individually to each of the members of the section, to change the section itself I needed to wrap it in a stack. I used a VStack but ZStacks are good for backgrounds.

Comment: @MichaelSalmon I tried this `ZStack {
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red)
                Section {
                    Text("Error message")
                }
            }`, but the problem remains, there is still a padding for the background

Comment: You don't need the rectangle, Color.red works just as well. A little tip, in Xcode under Debug->View Debugging you can fetch the View Hierarchy. If I read it correctly it shows that Form is built using a UITableView and the border is from that table view. Form and section sound good but do you really need them?

Comment: On a totally different subject, I found that non opaque backgrounds don't look good in dark mode, a Color with the right hue (0 here), saturation equal to opacity and brightness 1.0 for light mode and 0.7 for dark mode seems to work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help, at least in Simulator this seems to be a solution to your request:

```
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Error message!")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(Color.red.opacity(0.2))

                Section {
                    Text("Label 1")
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Label 2")
                }
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
```

Comment: It seems that `listRowBackground<V>(_ view: V?)` on the `HStack` also works, then the paddings are not needed anymore

Answer (score 1):

Add `.listRowBackground(Color.red.opacity(0.2))` to your section

```
NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Error message!")
                 }.listRowBackground(Color.red.opacity(0.2))

                Section {
                    Text("Label 1")
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Label 2")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode.inline)
        }
```

and if you want to clear the background of a section use:

`.listRowBackground(Color.clear)`

if you want to make the list transparent add the above to sections and add this to your list:

`.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)`

on the list